# Joining Meshes and then textures

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

since you did a fantastic job last time I thought I'd bug you all again. After a grand total of a day and a half total experience I was able to make this horribly optimized monstrosity.

[image: New Zealand DJ Class Locomotive]

What I'd like to do, is join all of these together and then create a texture for it, so it's not grey, faceless and ugly, it'll just be ugly.

Is there anything I need to do or will pushing A and then Ctrl J be fine? :/

[image: Join all the bits down to a single mesh?]

When I tried this last time and went over to make the new texture and link everything together so I could paint it the blank texture started like this? I seem to remember it being blank before? Now it has lines?

[image: Is it meant to do this?]

If I try and use it, it's a single mesh as intended, and I can add the texture file in but it only affects half the model? So, I'm most likely horribly screwing this up, which is par for the course. How can I get it combined into a single mesh and get some textures going that, if possible, will paint the whole thing? :)

Thanks so much, as always! :)

[image: Half black and less ugly, half grey and still ugly]

Comment: Joining doesn't actually fuse the parts together. It's almost like it merely groups them. I say this because they can be separated later with a single command. You could make the whole thing one single mesh. Joining would be the first step if you actually want to fuse them. You would just have to go in afterwards and merge the relevant vertices to make the whole model one continuous, manifold mesh. Once that's done, designate seams as necessary and, with all faces selected, unwrap. Then all of the model's parts will be in the same texture space. And you can paint on the whole thing at once.

Comment: A simpler alternative approach to the above would be to go ahead and separate the parts again, and texture them separately, then join them back together afterwards. This might save you some tedium in the modeling department, but it would be less intuitive while texture painting.

Comment: One last thing: I mentioned designating seams, but, in a mechanical subject like this, designating seams is likely unnecessary. Especially if you intend to do all of your texturing with Blender's built in texture painting tools (as opposed to editing the texture externally in a program like Photoshop). If relying on the Texture Paint tools exclusively, then it's probably better to use Smart UV Unwrap, even though it tends to produce nonsensical mappings. That won't matter if all you're ever using to build the texture is the Texture Paint brushes in Blender.